# Implicit Function Theorem and coordinate systems near a level set of a function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, implicit-function-theorem

Suppose I have an $(x,y)$ coordinate system. I have a zero level set of a smooth function $H(x,y)$, i.e. $H(x,y)=0$. Suppose this level set is parametrised by a parameter $t$, i.e. $(x(t), y(t))$.

I want to apply implicit function theorem to show that I can use the functions $(H, t)$ as a system of well-defined coordinates in some neighbourhood of this zero level set.

How do I set up the implicit function theorem for this and what assumptions I need to make? And in particular, under what conditions is $H$ $\mathbf{not}$ a good coordinate?

Edit. Further, from what geometrical considerations can I infer whether $(H,t)$ is a good systems of coordinates? (i.e. non-vanishing of gradient of $H$, etc...?)

Answer (score 1):

If $\nabla H(x_0,y_0)\ne (0,0)$, one of the partial derivatives is $\ne 0$ and by the implicit function theorem:
$$
\partial_x H(x_0,y_0)\ne 0\implies x\hbox{ can be written locally as function of } y: H(X(y),y) = 0
$$
$$
\partial_y H(x_0,y_0)\ne 0\implies y\hbox{ can be written locally as function of } x: H(x,Y(x)) = 0
$$
In any case, you have your first condition. For the second condition, suppose wolg $\partial_y H(x_0,y_0)\ne 0$.
You want
$$(x,y)\longmapsto (x,H(x,y))$$
be locally a diffeomorphism. Calculating the differential at $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0\cr
\partial_x H(x_0,y_0)&\partial_y H(x_0,y_0)
}
$$
and this matrix is inversible:
$$
\left|\matrix{
1&0\cr
\partial_x H(x_0,y_0)&\partial_y H(x_0,y_0)
}\right| = \partial_y H(x_0,y_0)\ne 0.
$$
Now, apply the inverse function theorem.